# TypeORM afterInsert locks DB on foreign entity update

Tags: node.js, database, typeorm

I have an `EventSubscriber` on my `Answer` entity. When an `Answer` gets created, I want to update a field on my `User` entity.

I started with a normal `afterInsert` on the `Answer` entity, but it locked the database and never altered `User`. I noticed the documentation says:

> **Note**: Do not make any database calls within a listener, opt for subscribers instead.

So, I made a subscriber which gets called as expected, but has the same problem of locking the DB and hanging on `user.save()`. I've tried `beforeInsert` and that actually works, but `afterInsert` does not.

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class PersonSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Answer> {
  listenTo() {
    return Answer;
  }

  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Answer>) {
    console.log("I get called");

    const user = await AppDataSource.getRepository(User).findOne({
      where: {
        id: event.entity.user.id,
      },
    });

    console.log("I also get called");

    user.sessionCount = 100;
    await user.save();

    // await AppDataSource.getRepository(User).save(user); // doesn't work either

    console.log("I do not get called");
  }
}
```

*****Edit: Got it!*****

I needed to use the `EntityManager` on the event itself instead of using `AppDataSource`. Something like:

```
await event.manager.save(event.entity.user);
```

I'll leave the question open, as I'd like an explanation on why this didn't work the original way I had it.